# Kotlin: EditText is null in afterTextChanged()

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, android-lifecycle, android-textwatcher

I have an `EditText` and I'm setting an error into it or dismiss the error after text changes. However somehow I'm getting *NPE* when trying to access the `EditText` from the `afterTextChanged()` method.

```
phone_number_input.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher() {
        ...
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            if (isValid(s.toString()) 
                phone_number_input.error = null // <-- NPE happens here
            else
                phone_number_input.error = "Number is invalid"
        }
    })
```

It's not reproducing constantly, but for the last month there were dozens of crashes on different devices starting from *Android* 4.4.2 up to 6.0.1.

How can that happen? If `Fragment` is destroyed, `TextWatcher` shouldn't be called, right? How can it be prevented?

Comment: Try to add `this@Activity/Fragment.phone_number_input...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can that happen?

Most likely, when this happens your app goes to foreground while user is typing (e.g. due to an incoming call).

> If `Fragment` is destroyed, `TextWatcher` shouldn't be called, right?

Right. But you're missing the order in which `Fragment` and `Layout` inflated "within" it get destroyed. The destruction for those two aren't done simultaneously - `Layout` gets destroyed first.

As you can see, the `TextWatcher` is an [anonymous inner class instance that keeps reference to its outer class](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html), your `Fragment`, which is to be destroyed last. The key point here is so that any text changes within `EditText` coming from the `TextWatcher` are done asynchronously - your app's process view gets "notifications" from another process in the system, soft keyboard app ([default one](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/jb-dev/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/latin)).

In case when such a "notification" comes at a time your `EditText` has been destroyed but your `Fragment` has not, you get *NPE*.

> How can it be prevented?

Simply use `phone_number_input?.error = ...`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, small note to the note, it is ok to use `s.toString` on nullable type as kotlin has extension for that `public fun Any?.toString(): String` and it will return `"null"` in case `s` is `null`